# File upload + hash gives me a problem when size is greater than max size

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm noticing something strange and was wondering if someone could test my code on their side and let me know if they get the same thing.

I have a real simple form (see full form code and action code below) which only has a file upload + hidden hash + submit button. The file upload has a max size limit set to 10000000 (about 9.5MB).

When I try to upload a file bigger than the limit, the form isn't supposed to validate, but I get an error in the hash token itself `Value is required and can't be empty`. Can someone confirm? It looks like the token is being wiped out. I'm guessing this could happen in the case of a redirect or something, but I'm not doing any redirects, unless there's something happening in the background that I'm not noticing.

Here's the form code and my action code

```
class Application_Form_TestForm extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {   

    $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
    $file->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH);
    $file->addValidator('Size', false, 10000000);
    $file->setMaxFileSize(10000000);
    $this->addElement($file);

    $hash = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('hash');
    $hash->setIgnore(true)
         ->setSalt('mysalt');
    $this->addElement($hash);  

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');       
    $submit->setLabel('Test')
           ->setIgnore(true);            
    $this->addElement($submit);  

    $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $this->setMethod('post');
}
}
```

In my controller, I do the usual validation

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_TestForm();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if($this->_request->isPost()){          
        echo "post";
        if($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())){
           echo " valid";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to your post_max_size or upload_max_filesize values in your php.ini. For example, default value of post_max_size is 8M which is less than your max file size.

Comment: You were right again. Both values are 64MB in my php.ini. When I upload a file between the form max (9.5) and php max (64), I get the `file exceeded size` error, but when I go over the php max (64) I get this strange error with the token. So my next question is: still I don't understand why the file size has anything to do with the hash element. Is there a redirect in the background?

Comment: @jblue. I think that if you exceed your post_max_size, yout $_POST variable will be empty. You can check it in your action (var_dump($_POST)). Thus as far as Zend Form in concerned, no values were submitted by your form.